# Are there any "compact" themes for Android?

Tags: themes

So that I can only see the desktop icons, not the ex.: messaging, applications, call icon in the bottom..Are there any compat'er views for the Android Desktop?

Android 2.1update1 Samsung GT i5800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

- Install [ADW Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher) as your home application and set it as default
- From your home screen press `Menu Button->More->ADWSettings` to open ADW's settings
- Select `UI Settings->Main Dock Style->None` to hide the bottom bar
- Optionally, you can also select `Screen Preferences->Hide StatusBar` to hide the status bar at the top, which effectively makes your home take up the entire screen.